# How to compare tow date in Having clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve products which have been never commanded after a date, so that's basically what I do:

```
SELECT P.* FROM Produits P 
INNER JOIN Commandes C ON C.numprod = P.numprod 
GROUP BY P.numprod, P.designation, P.numfour, P.prix 
HAVING MAX(C.datec) < '2017-05-09'
```

But it's only work if I use equal sign next to `MAX()`, and return nothing in that case. I will be appreciated for any Clarification and sorry for any language mistakes.

Comment: What kind of error do you get if you don't use a `max` on `c.datec`?

Comment: No! I don't get any error just empty answer ever if I have date less than '2017-05-09'

Comment: Your query should work.  Perhaps no products fit that description.

Comment: You're right I have no products fit the description, thank you!

Comment: That query (exactly as we see it above) should not work in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're getting an error that says something like `invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause...` and that's why you're using a `max` on the `having` statement. Using max on that statement resolves the error but gives you the biggest date, that is why you're likely not getting any results back.

Try:

```
select *
from
(SELECT P.* FROM Produits P 
INNER JOIN Commandes C ON C.numprod = P.numprod 
where C.datec < '2017-05-09'
) t
GROUP BY t.numprod, t.designation, t.numfour, t.prix
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, Would you to tell me about this syntax because I had never learned about it, and your solution return commanded products before that date and I want those who never commanded again after that date?

Comment: This question's tag is for sql-server, you cannot assume that `select *` and `group by` will work without error.  (Quite unlike MySQL which can make dangerous assumptions about the data and produce a potentially misleading result with this type of lazy syntax adherence.)

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove this type of error `"invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause..."`

```
SELECT P.numprod, P.designation, P.numfour, P.prix  -- include the grouping columns
FROM Produits P 
INNER JOIN Commandes C ON C.numprod = P.numprod 
GROUP BY P.numprod, P.designation, P.numfour, P.prix 
HAVING MAX(C.datec) < '2017-05-09'
```

If no data is returned by that query it is because no maximum date is equal or later than the specified date in the having clause.

For this: `"retrieve products which have been never commanded after a date,..."` I suggest the following

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Produits P 
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT numprod
        FROM Commandes
        WHERE datec > '2017-05-09'
        GROUP BY numprod
        ) AS C ON P.numprod = C.numprod 
WHERE C.numprod IS NULL
```

Using this approach you locate all products which DO have a date after the wanted date, then by using a left join we can identfy all unmatched product rows which will be all products that which "*have been never commanded after [that] date*"